# MailMessage and SmtpClient fails on Windows 8.1

Tags: smtpclient

I’m facing the following issue on multiple (not to say: all) Windows 8.x machines:

Running this piece of code:

```
var message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("sender@foo.bar.com");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient1@foo.bar.com"));

message.Subject = "This is my subject";
message.Body = "This is the content";

var client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```

The config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="test@foo.com">
            <network host="smtpserver1" port="25" userName="username" password="secret" defaultCredentials="false" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

against a hosted Exchange Server results in several issues like `5.7.1` SMTP errors (not authenticated, base64 required etc.)

Running the same code on a Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012 or Windows 7 works as expected…
Turning of the firewall did not help.

Am I missing same magic on Windows 8.1 machines?

It doesn't matter whether the code runs in an IIS or Console Application.
Setting `defaultCredentials` to `true` or `false` also doesn't matter.

Sending the mail using Windows telnet client works without any problems also.

**Update:
Here comes the WireShark SMTP Log:**

```
C: EHLO <LOCALMACHINENAME>
S: 250 mail.myhostedexchange.org Hello [<IP>] | 250 SIZE 104857600 | 250 PIPELINING | 250 DSN | 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES | 250 STARTTLS | 250 AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN | 250 8BITMIME | 250 BINARYMIME | 250 CHUNKING
C: AUTH gssapi <base64 encoded string>
S: 334 <base64 encoded string>
C: base64 username
S: 334 <base64 encoded string>
C: base64 password
S: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

**Update 2:**
I compared the Wireshark output from a Windows 8.1 machine and a Windows 7 machine (where everything works fine):

The Windows 7 machine sends something like this:

```
C: AUTH gssapi <base64encoded>NTLMSSP + some encoded chars.
```

The Windows 8 machine sends something like this:

```
C: AUTH gssapi <somehowencodedchars>Token Signing Public Key<somehowencodedchars>WELLKNOWN:PKU2U<somehowencodedchars>SMTPSVCmail.myhostedexchange.org
```

**Update 3:**

I tried using SendGrid and it works fine on Windows 8.x machines.
The difference between SendGrid and my Hosted Exchange is that SendGrid only supports

`250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN`

This is similar to my Telnet Login experience.

**Update 4:**
`EnableSSL=true` does not fix it.

Comment: I just created a Console Application (.NET v4.5.1; Windows 8.1 Pro) and copied your code and config snippet. Changed the config and mail addresses and it works without any problems.

Comment: Weird. Tested it on multiple machines and didn't get it working.

Comment: The weird thing is that there is no consistent error.

Comment: I'd suggest to log the SMTP conversation with wireshark or something similar and have a look at that.

Comment: @escitalopram added the Wireshark log to my post.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to this bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785710/mailmessage-subject-incorrectly-encoded-in-utf-8-base64 but this is just with the subject header and not authentication. Keep reading!

Before I changed my answer I was pointing to the Exchange server as the problem. Encoding CSR.  (but then changed my approach to the client to see what could be done there since it seemed like Weekend changes server-side would have a lower probability. But then again it just might be the right way to go after all.

I have fetched that information and brought it back:

[Create a new CSR on the Exchange server and reissue the certificate](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-exchange-2010.htm)

And review this post where a base64 was request to exchange but failed. So the Exchange Server had to have something modified.

http://www.billmorefield.com/index.php/2013/11/29/encoding-csr-on-exchange-2010/

I am seeing a lot of the 64 base interpretation on various different things pointing to a backwards compatibility issue on your exchange server.  Windows 8 is throwing something at it and Exchange folds because of interpretation problems.

More client related but along the same lines to try to avoid bumping the 64base encrypt/decrypting problem...Here is a work around attempt from the client side which is basically rendering SSL auth useless (leaving this just to illustrate that people are attempting to approach this from the client side). See if you can set SMTPEnableSSL=N or false in your web config settings. Test and see if it works. I am thinking SSL might be the problem.

http://theoldsewingfactory.com/2011/01/06/enable-ssl-in-web-config-for-smtpclient/

Look here as well. I'll pretty up these links later.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/023d7598-9311-4b84-b1df-81ceda011fe4/bug-smtplivecom-stopped-working-after-win-81-tested-ol2013-win8-my-lan-roaming-user?forum=w81previtpro

This is backwards compatibility issue.

This is for the .NET 4 framework. If you are using 3.5 or 3 it won't work in config.

So then you would look for your host settings somewhere and configure it there.

Reason seems to be due to the base 64 encryption not being able decrypt on your SMTP server.

Ok. To bring back my main points.  It is unlikely that this is a Application coding problem considering the code works on some Windows 8 machines with SMTP and older versions of client server setups.  This is more related a transport/authentication issue.

Console app
using telnet
on windows 8.1
connecting to a hosted 2010 exchange server.

Approach: Authentication/Security/Relay

Here are some better things to check.

Authentication (this is for sharepoint but it talks about your config file).

**Machine Keys**

[Machine Keys](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11150/sharepoint-2010-updates-the-machine-key-in-web-config)

[More Machine keys](http://kx.cloudingenium.com/programming/net/you-must-specify-a-non-autogenerated-machine-key-to-store-passwords-in-the-encrypted-format-either-specify-a-different-passwordformat-or-change-the-machinekey-configuration-to-use-a-non-autogenera/)

**Client Certificates**

[Client Certificates and Windows 8](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb517a69-5a4e-48c3-b9cc-f740f78be9df/new-windows-81-clients-getting-certificate-error?forum=exchangesvrclients)

More on Certificates

[Certificate Authority](https://smtpport25.wordpress.com/tag/certificate-authority/)

**SSL**

[Here is discussion on routers, SSL and Windows 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/browsers-mail/10137-windows-8-mail-app-digital-certificate.html)

[Here is discussion on Multiple Authoritative Domains and Windows 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996314%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I tried sending it from an IIS hosted application and also using from Console Application. Both failed.

Comment: Ok making a few more discoveries.  It looks like you are using IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1....Is this correct? I am looking at some more server config stuff.

Comment: No, I'm using a Console Application on Windows 8.1 against a Hosted Exchange 2010 Server.

Comment: Ok that is helpful. I am looking at Application security configurations and considerations.

Comment: To be more specific: Computer is not part of a domain but has a uses Microsoft Account instead.

Comment: Oh I see. Ok lets take a look and see what we have in the way of MS accounts and non-domain managed accounts.  I think we are getting closer here.

Comment: Added the Wireshark log to my post.

Comment: That is useful.  I think the problem needs to be approached in this order...I will update my response with the trouble shooting parameters.

Comment: Alex.  I believe you'll need to talk to your Exchange Administrator and have him get your Authorization/Access fixed.

Comment: Wow...This was a frenzied session. I have to go to a birthday party now.  So I will check in on this later this evening to see where you are at with answers and additional information if you have any more to provide.  BUT I think you have given us a GOOD set of info to work with!

Comment: Thanks, have fun - I just added some more Wireshark details to my post.

Comment: Ok. It seems to be SSL related. I have updated my answer and I don't like this solution but the more I read the more this becomes a work around as opposed to a 'good' solution.

Comment: EnableSSL=true did not fix it.

Comment: EnableSSL = false (not true). What .NET framework is this?  I am assuming the code is VB .NET? (4.5 is the latest).

Comment: Nevermind.  I have revised my answer back to the exchange server where the catch needs to be handled.  I think I am going to leave this as the answer instead of hitting a client change attempt then back to server config change and vise verse.